# Created Hive tables STORED BY ICEBER; SELECT * returns empty

Tags: sql, hive, archive, apache-iceberg

I'm trying to implement a lakehous with hive 4 and iceberg and i think i'm almost there but...
When I create a table like:
`CREATE TABLE ice (id INT, name STRING) STORED BY ICEBERG;`

And then insert some data
`INSERT INTO ice VALUES (1, 'one');`

And then select
`SELECT * FROM ice;`
I don't see the inserted record.

I do see the parquet files on storage, and see the folder and file of the metadata, as if the table was created as location_based_table. But the [documentation says](https://iceberg.apache.org/docs/latest/hive/#catalog-management) that if no specific iceberg.catalog is set, it will use the defaul hive catalog.

What am I missing?
I suspect that is something related to the metastore, but can't find what...

I do see the parquet files on storage, and see the folder and file of the metadata, as if the table was created as location_based_table. But documentation says that if no specific iceberg.catalog is set, it will use the default hive catalog.